# does ruby on rails automatically lock active record associations when locking the active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, locking, associations

Pretty basic question:

I have a model x that has_many y, and model y belong_to x.

If I lock an instance of model x with id x_id, does it also lock the associated rows in the table for model y which has has value x_id under the join column?

Or does ror locking just lock the active record and does not care about its associations?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i know, it would not lock any associations. It just locks rows, without caring for model associations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if there are [two locking strategies in rails](http://bandwagonblog.wordpress.com/2009/01/24/activerecord-locking/), optimistic (which doesn't actually lock rows but ActiveRecord raises ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError for multiple updates to the same row [except the first update, which will succeed]), and pessimistic (which appends `FOR UPDATE` to the select statement and actually locks the rows (assuming your database supports locking).  None of the [ActiveRecord Locking documentation I read through](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking.html) implies that there is any magic that causes/allows associative records to be locked.

Since you can pass your own locking clause, I would suggest on reading up on how your specific database handles the clause rails uses for pessimistic locking (`select ... for update`) and other clauses that you can pass (Using [ActiveRecord#lock!](http://railsapi.com/doc/rails-v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Locking/Pessimistic.html#M001345)).

Comment: So, lets say model X has a has_many association with model Y. I get an instance of model X, x, with lock in share mode. Ideally, this should not allow any updates to the model from other threads. But since associations are not taken into account, another thread can modify the has_many association (e.g. x.ys << foo)? If this is true, how can I prevent this from happening??

Comment: @dhruvg Yes, you are correct.  If you want to lock associations on the X object, you would have to write some initialization code that manually went through and locked all the Y's related to X.  Seems like a lot of overhead.  Are you sure you *need* to lock all these related entities? Perhaps there is a more elegant way to achieve what you want, or you might be able to find a gem that extends the locking behavior already in ActiveRecord without writing too much code yourself.